# (OAuthException) (#200) exception while posting to facebook wall using facebook c#sdk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

i am working on asp.net mvc3 and i am using facebook c# sdk to post on fb wall . i get following error while trying to post on wall.

(OAuthException) (#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories

please see the code i used .

string appAccessToken = "accessstoken"; //this token i got after creatting app in fb developer.

```
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(appAccessToken);
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                                    {
                                                        {"description", "Testbeskrivning"},
                                                        {"link", ""},
                                                        {"name", "Testtitel" }

                                                    };

        fb.Post("myfbid/feed", parameters);
```

Comment: hi please find the solution for above code.

Comment: for above code to work download facebook c# sdk 5.2.1 . then include facebook.dll from .net 4.0 client folder to our proj .add namespace using facebook in page .then call above method.In above method access token you can by pasting this url in your browser then giving proper app id from facebook and url which is same as canvas url set in your fb app.  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=appid&redirect_uri=canvasurlsetinfb-oursitename&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token . in the redirected page you can see access token in the url .use that.

Comment: dont forget to add message in parameter otherwise ur post will be empty in wall. add { "message","your message"} to parameter list

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't added the right permission when you get the LoginUrl:
You will have to add the following permission: **publish_stream**.

```
var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current);
oAuthClient.RedirectUri = new Uri(redirectUrl);

Dictionary<String, Object> oParams = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
oParams.Add("scope", "publish_stream");

var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(oParams);
```

For the most Facebook features you need the permissions from the users.
Check the following page for all the current permissions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/